# Find the record which is inserted the most in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contains user id, user revenue etc. The table may contain more than two insertion for a particular user id.
My task is to get the user id who has got the highest number of insertion in the table. 
Can anyone help to write the query in php mysql...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research nor minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM users 
group by user_id 
order by count(user_id) DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

```
select user_id, count(*) from whatever_table group by user_id;
```

Might want to try to add some sorting in there too, but that's the gist.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you find the count of each user id? Then you may sort, append to results, or do anything you want.

Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Do a count with sorting and grouping.

```
select user_id, count(*) as count from
whatever_table group by user_id order
by count DESC limit 1;
```

`DESC` makes it start with the highest number and go backward. The `limit` statement makes it so only 1 record is returned.

Comment: Its working, i got the result..